# Remote database connection open for long time

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2008, connection, database-connection

I am executing some crud's on mssql server 2008 database by connecting remotely. I have business logic in Java with tight code for connection, statement and result set close() in finally block.
My doubt is, even when I finish the job the connection port are still open and it takes roughly 20 min to close all connections. I can view the open connection using netstat -a command.
I need to quickly close the connections since each operation opens/close connection several times. Hence I see large number of connections open. This is very insecure and costly  to keep so many unwanted connections for long time which the business logic has already closed.
I am using the latest jtds.jar file. Any hint or suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Akshay

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;

ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    // Do stuff
    ...

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // Exception handling stuff
    ...
} finally {
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
    }
    if (ps != null) {
        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code for database operation. Code would help you rather than few sentences.

Comment: As i said above its nothing to do with code. I see the connection conn,stmt and resultset getting closed evidently in debug mode. Either it the Garbage collector issue which is rare, since it takes 10-20 min. May be some db system setting issue.

Comment: The connection you see using netstat-a, are they in WAIT_TIME state ?

Comment: database have no control over the connection created by an application. Well it can close an existing connection but can not a connection live if application wants it closed.

Comment: @Santosh Yes some are in "wait_time" some are "established". The connection with wait_time take longer to terminate.(May be bcoz they are waiting for connection in the pool?)

Comment: @user1428768 wait_time should not be a worry. Check this [blog](http://j2eedebug.blogspot.in/2008/12/difference-between-closewait-and.html). This nicely explains different stats a network socket goes through. Please make sure that the `Established`are the connection actually the DB connection which you say you closed.

Comment: I will narrow the problem further and update my comment soon...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys and Thanks for taking out time to answer my question.
The connection close was a framework call which was not closing properly. I didn't had access to it so I thought that was not the issue. Thank you once again for your time and guidance.