# Oracle connection never dies

Tags: .net, oracle, connection

I am working with Oracle from "net". All works fine, but the connection never dies. 
What I need to do, to kill the connection? 
While the program is running, keep going growing the number of connections...
I tried everithing.

[image: my code]

[image: Oracle connections logs]

Thanks in advance!!
Regards!
Guille

Comment: Looks like behavior is universal and your question is doomed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038836/remote-database-connection-open-for-long-time. I personally think that actual DB connection is closed. What remaining is the port connection. But DB will not likely to except another call on that closed connection.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the `cn.Close()` in your code. Call this before `cn.Dispose()`.

Comment: `cn.Dispose` will close it

Comment: Anyway, _Close/Dispose connections explicitly_ : [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/ow2011-bp-performance-deploy-dotnet-518050.pdf)